# Creating a partial function that sets a keyword argument in the original function

Tags: python, arguments, wrapper, partial, functools

Not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to create a partial function from a function with positional and keyword arguments.  The problem is, I want the argument in the resulting partial function to set one of the keyword arguments in the original function - not one of its positional arguments.

Here is the original function's definition:

```
def cost_function(self, X, y, weights=None, lambda_param=0.0):
```

I want a partial function that I can pass to scipy.minimise so I can find the optimum weights values (weights is an ndarray).

So what I need is a partial function with just one argument (x say):

E.g.

```
cost_func(x)
```

But I want the partial function to set the weights argument when it calls the original function:

```
my_network.cost_function(X, y, weights=x, lambda_param=0.0)
```

(I know I could change the original function so that the weights argument is positional not a keyword argument but I don't want to do that because I also want to use the function without a weights argument set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that functools.partial meet your needs

See example:

```
import functools
def cost_function(self, X, y, weights=None, lambda_param=0.0):
    print (weights)

cost_func = functools.partial(cost_function, None, 20, 30, lambda_param=2.0)


print (cost_func("Yay it worked!!!"))
```

Comment: Indeed, you're quite right!  I guess I didn't realize that the argument weight actual has a position (even though it has a keyword) so it will be filled by the value in position 4 even if no keyword is specified.  Thanks!